# Setting x.domain with setInterval

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

modify this question again, because the solution does not work in the new version of the library d3 (3.0.3), so I come to ask for some help again would be very grateful.

Here is the new code with the library d3 (3.0.3):

https://gist.github.com/4495104
http://bl.ocks.org/4495104/e7a7589098140dff36df7ab2a824d71072bc3be4

According to what I've worked, the error should be in the line "491".

```
// Reset the domain relative to the current zoom offsets.
    x.domain(x0.range().map(function(x) {
      return (x - translate[0]) / scale; 
    }).map(x0.invert));
```

We are changing the `x.domain` every second with `setInterval`, because we want to generate the appearance that the background is moving, but every time you run an event `d3.behavior.zoom()` (zoom or panning) the `x.domain` automatically switches to the initial values​​. In the next link you can review the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/cristian540/Uy6bW/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the scale's domain programmatically, you need to reassign the scale to the zoom behaviour. This is because the zoom behaviour stores a clone of the scale internally for computing the new domain for new scale and translate offsets. So if you don't reassign the scale, it continues to use the (old) cloned scale.

I've updated the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#wiki-x) to include a note about this.

There is an additional complication, which is that the zoom's x- and y-scales should represent the domains at zoom scale=1. So you actually need to keep your own clone of the current scale(s) at zoom scale=1 and apply the offset to both the clones and the current scales.

Then, you may also need to invert the current zoom translate and scale, depending on the exact behaviour that you need.

So it should look something like:

```
var x0 = d3.scale.linear().domain(…).range(…), // initial scale
    x = x0.copy(); // copy to use for axes and zoom behaviour

setInterval(function() {
  var translate = zoom.translate(),
      scale = zoom.scale(),
      xd = x0.domain(),
      dx = 1;

  // Set a new x-domain: offset by dx.
  x0.domain([xd[0] += dx, xd[1] += dx]);

  // Set the zoom x-domain (this resets the domain at zoom scale=1).
  zoom.x(x.domain(xd));

  // Reset the domain relative to the current zoom offsets.
  x.domain(x0.range().map(function(x) {
    return (x - translate[0]) / scale;
  }).map(x0.invert));
}, 1e3);
```

[Example](http://bl.ocks.org/3743077) of this in action.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you early response,
We implemented the recomendation that you give us, and we set the new domain every second but we have detected a error, when we apply zoom in it works perfectly but when i try to zoom out it doesn't work, it doesn't allow me make a zoom out however it makes some movements in the graphs but always with the last d3.behavior.zoom() domain that i set.

Comment: We though that for solve we must set the d3.behavior.zoom() domain with the domain that belong to the scale 1 but with your respective shift in "X", but that is not easy to set, is there a way to set the domain of the zoom behavior without set the x.domain?

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to reset the translation vector appropriately too. I've updated the answer to include this along with an example. Unfortunately, I think there's a bug in D3, where the drift vector is not reset if the translate vector is reset. See here for fix: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/810

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your early response, but I have a doubt, the bug that you said related to resetting the drift vector when the mouse hasn't moved, is that which occurs when zooming in and then zooming out we lost the x.domain?. I noted in the example that you give us that the problem with the zoom out continue, is that related with the bug that you have mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise what you meant, so my example didn't really solve your original question. I've fixed it now and updated the answer, hopefully that makes more sense. You may not need the last bit to invert the current zoom translate/scale. The drift vector bug doesn't apply here any more since you're not resetting the translate/scale.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help was very useful to us. :D